# Is it possible to use return value of a method in another method?

Tags: java, methods

Hello I'm trying to do this homework and I should write a method that gets some information from other methods that I wrote. (e.g. car type,dates,extras etc.) .So my question is, can i use return values of these methods in my final method without calling them again? This is my main method:

```
public class Homework3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        char customer = 'O';
        int numberOfCustomers = 0;
        int totalEarning= 0;
        while(customer != 'N'){
            System.out.println("Car Type is " + promptForCarType());
            System.out.println("Car rented for " + calculateDays() + " days.");
            promptForExtras();
            System.out.printf("\nTotal : %d TL",calculateTotal() );
            totalEarning += calculateTotal();
            numberOfCustomers ++;
            System.out.println("Number of customers : " + numberOfCustomers);
            System.out.println("Total amount earned : " + totalEarning);
            while(customer != 'N' || customer != 'Y'){
                System.out.println("A new customer? (Y/N)");
                customer = input.next().charAt(0);
                customer = Character.toUpperCase(customer);
            }
        }
    }
```

And I should use car type, days, extras in my calculateTotal() method. I also tried to assign other methods' return values as variables and using them in my final method as parameters but didn't work.For example i tried to write something like this :

```
public static int calculateTotal(){
            int total=0;
            int time = calculateDays();
            int rate = (time / 7)*5    + (time % 7);

            if(promptForCarType().equals("Economy"))
                total += 50*rate;
            else if(promptForCarType().equals("Midsize"))
                total += 70*rate;
            else if(promptForCarType().equals("Fullsize"))
                total += 100*rate;


            total += promptForExtras() * time;
            return total;
        }
```

but when i call calculateTotal() in my main method, it automatically calls calculateDays() again

Comment: So what error do you get?

Comment: Of course you can return data from one method call to another.  Your example does not have any methods, except Main(), so what is the problem you are having?

Comment: yes you definitely can do this. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Have you written any methods yet?

Comment: There are no errors.For example, it calls the method again and asks user for the pick-up and return dates again , when I try to use days to calculate total amount

Comment: `totalEarning += calculateTotal();` What do you think this does if not "use [the] return value of a method in another method"?

Comment: @Kevin _So my question is, can i use return values of these methods in my final method without calling them again?_ this is what I wrote as my question .`totalEarning += calculateTotal();` it uses return value after calling it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bascially, what could do, is pass in the value from `calculateDays` to `calculateTotal` so you don't need to calculate it again...

```
System.out.println("Car Type is " + promptForCarType());
in days = calculateDays();
System.out.println("Car rented for " + days + " days.");
promptForExtras();
System.out.printf("\nTotal : %d TL",calculateTotal(days) );
```

Then you would need to change `calculateTotal` to allow it to accept the value you want to pass it...

```
public static int calculateTotal(int time){
    int total=0;
    int rate = (time / 7)*5    + (time % 7);
    //...
```

For example...